# error while reloading spring properties with @RefreshScope in spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm testing one prototype for spring-cloud using @RefreshScope annotation. I'm using one external property file for that. Which I have provided and configured in runtime argument.

pom.xml dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.proto.reload</groupId>
<artifactId>CachingService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CachingService</name>
<description>Demo project for cache</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId> 
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is main class

```
package com.proto.reload;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.ApplicationPidFileWriter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CachingServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Commandline argument. Please provide Consumer Properties file.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(CachingServiceApplication.class)
            .listeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter())
            .properties("spring.config.name:" + args[0].replaceAll(".properties", ""))
            .build()
            .run(args);

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(ConfigClass.getName());
    }
}

}
```

Config class having @RefreshScope annotation

```
package com.proto.reload;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigClass {

    private static String name;

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Value("${app.prop.name}")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And this is property file I'm passing through argument

```
app.prop.name=FirstOldValue

spring.pid.file=TestOne.pid
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
   12:38:41.051 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, ...]
12:38:41.105 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at com.proto.reload.CachingServiceApplication.main(CachingServiceApplication.java:19)
```

Am I using @RefreshScope in wrong way ?
This code works fine when I remove dependency and @RefreshScope, but its not updating property value at runtime. My goal is to load modified property value at runtime.

Comment: Please add your full POM, this looks like a dependency mis-match. You should be using Spring Cloud BOM or Parent POM to keep the Spring Cloud dependencies in line with Spring Boot

Comment: @Darren Updated full pom content please check

Comment: Yup, incompatible versions.

Answer (score 1):

`1.1.8.RELEASE` for Spring Cloud is part of the Camden Release train which is for Spring Boot `1.4.x` releases.

Please see the `Release Trains` section for what release train to use for your Spring Boot version

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Currently they are,

> Release Train     Boot Version
>
> Greenwich        2.1.x
>
> Finchley         2.0.x
>
> Edgware          1.5.x
>
> Dalston          1.5.x

As your using spring boot 2.1.1 your dependency management should look like the below, note as Greenwich doesn't have a `RELEASE` yet you need to add the milestone repository.

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigClass {
    @Value("${app.prop.name}")
    private static String name;

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add cloud context depedency and try again

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update :
it is just not a valid use case to have @Configuration and @RefreshScope on the same element. As per this URL thread : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/43

Comment: Tried what you suggested but still same error report

Comment: see this example about how to use refreshscope : https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: Configuration and RefreshScope annotation cannot be used on same element as mentioned by me earlier ....have you gone through that ?

Comment: I have seprated both annotation. Used RefreshScope, ComponentScan at config class, and used EnableAutoConfiguration at main class. Still not helping it. Some configuration is still missing